# How to copy a file from my Windows Server 2016 to a network folder that has only write permission?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have to move a file from my server to a network folder with only write permission.

I tried to use "net use" to map the folder, but I'm getting "The user is not allowed to log on from this workstation." Is this message related to the fact I don't have read permission? If so, how can I copy the file to the remote folder?

Comment: try `\\servername\full\path\to\folder`

Comment: Hi jsotola,

I tried to mount the network drive before copying the file like so:

NET USE Z: \\servername\full\path\to\folder /USER:domain\UserName /persistent:No

I'm getting the error I mentioned:
"System error 2240 has occurred. The user is not allowed to log on from this workstation."

Is there a  windows command I can use to copy the file without mapping the folder to a drive letter?

Comment: you already said that `net use` command fails ... just try using the path in a copy command

Comment: Getting this error message:
 This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer.
 0 file(s) copied.

Comment: then ask the network admin to grant you access